# WAR file works on tomcat but will not install on JBoss EAP 5.1?

Tags: java, spring, jboss5.x

WAR file works on tomcat but will not install on JBoss EAP 5.1?.

I am using the admin console to upload my war file and I am getting the following error..

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: org.jboss.deployers.client.spi.IncompleteDeploymentException: Summary of incomplete deployments (SEE PREVIOUS ERRORS FOR DETAILS):

*** DEPLOYMENTS IN ERROR: Name -> Error

vfsfile:/var/lib/jbossas/server/default/deploy/MemberInquiry.war/ -> org.jboss.deployers.spi.DeploymentException: URL file:/var/lib/jbossas/server/default/deploy/MemberInquiry.war/ deployment failed


DEPLOYMENTS IN ERROR:
  Deployment "vfsfile:/var/lib/jbossas/server/default/deploy/MemberInquiry.war/" is in error due to the following reason(s): org.jboss.deployers.spi.DeploymentException: URL file:/var/lib/jbossas/server/default/deploy/MemberInquiry.war/ deployment failed

        at org.jboss.profileservice.management.client.upload.StreamingDeploymentTarget.invoke(StreamingDeploymentTarget.java:312)
        at org.jboss.profileservice.management.client.upload.StreamingDeploymentTarget.start(StreamingDeploymentTarget.java:189)
        at org.jboss.profileservice.management.client.upload.DeploymentProgressImpl.start(DeploymentProgressImpl.java:232)
        at org.jboss.profileservice.management.client.upload.DeploymentProgressImpl.run(DeploymentProgressImpl.java:89)
        at org.rhq.plugins.jbossas5.util.DeploymentUtils.run(DeploymentUtils.java:136)
        at org.rhq.plugins.jbossas5.AbstractManagedDeploymentComponent.invokeOperation(AbstractManagedDeploymentComponent.java:160)
        at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor1598.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:616)
        at org.rhq.core.pc.inventory.ResourceContainer$ComponentInvocationThread.call(ResourceContainer.java:525)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:334)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:166)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1110)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:603)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:679)
Caused by: org.jboss.deployers.client.spi.IncompleteDeploymentException: Summary of incomplete deployments (SEE PREVIOUS ERRORS FOR DETAILS):

*** DEPLOYMENTS IN ERROR: Name -> Error

vfsfile:/var/lib/jbossas/server/default/deploy/MemberInquiry.war/ -> org.jboss.deployers.spi.DeploymentException: URL file:/var/lib/jbossas/server/default/deploy/MemberInquiry.war/ deployment failed


DEPLOYMENTS IN ERROR:
  Deployment "vfsfile:/var/lib/jbossas/server/default/deploy/MemberInquiry.war/" is in error due to the following reason(s): org.jboss.deployers.spi.DeploymentException: URL file:/var/lib/jbossas/server/default/deploy/MemberInquiry.war/ deployment failed

        at org.jboss.deployers.plugins.deployers.DeployersImpl.checkComplete(DeployersImpl.java:1008)
        at org.jboss.deployers.plugins.deployers.DeployersImpl.checkComplete(DeployersImpl.java:954)
        at org.jboss.deployers.plugins.main.MainDeployerImpl.checkComplete(MainDeployerImpl.java:870)
        at org.jboss.system.server.profileservice.repository.MainDeployerAdapter.checkComplete(MainDeployerAdapter.java:128)
        at org.jboss.profileservice.management.upload.remoting.AbstractDeployHandler.start(AbstractDeployHandler.java:326)
        at org.jboss.profileservice.management.upload.remoting.AbstractDeployHandler.invoke(AbstractDeployHandler.java:238)
        at org.jboss.remoting.ServerInvoker.invoke(ServerInvoker.java:967)
        at org.jboss.remoting.transport.local.LocalClientInvoker.invoke(LocalClientInvoker.java:106)
        at org.jboss.remoting.Client.invoke(Client.java:2070)
        at org.jboss.remoting.Client.invoke(Client.java:879)
        at org.jboss.profileservice.management.client.upload.StreamingDeploymentTarget.invoke(StreamingDeploymentTarget.java:304)
        ... 14 more
```

here is my web.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns:web="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd"
    version="2.5"
    xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" >

    <listener >

        <listener-class >

org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener

        </listener-class>
    </listener>

    <context-param >

        <param-name >

contextConfigLocation

        </param-name>

        <param-value >


        /WEB-INF/applicationContext-security-LDAP-DEV.xml


        </param-value>
    </context-param>

    <filter >

        <filter-name >

springSecurityFilterChain

        </filter-name>

        <filter-class >


            org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy


        </filter-class>
    </filter>

    <filter-mapping >

        <filter-name >

springSecurityFilterChain

        </filter-name>

        <url-pattern >

/*

        </url-pattern>
    </filter-mapping>

    <context-param >

        <param-name >

log4jConfigLocation

        </param-name>

        <param-value >

/WEB-INF/classes/log4j.xml

        </param-value>
    </context-param>

    <servlet >

        <servlet-name >

dispatcher

        </servlet-name>

        <servlet-class >

org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet

        </servlet-class>

        <load-on-startup >

1

        </load-on-startup>
    </servlet>

    <servlet-mapping >

        <servlet-name >

dispatcher

        </servlet-name>

        <url-pattern >

*.html

        </url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>

    <welcome-file-list >

        <welcome-file >

index.html

        </welcome-file>

        <welcome-file >

index.jsp

        </welcome-file>
    </welcome-file-list>

    <listener >

        <listener-class >

org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener

        </listener-class>
    </listener>

    <listener >

        <listener-class >

org.springframework.security.web.session.HttpSessionEventPublisher

        </listener-class>
    </listener>

    <listener >

        <listener-class >

org.springframework.web.util.Log4jConfigListener

        </listener-class>
    </listener>


    <resource-ref>
        <description>DB Connection</description>
        <res-ref-name>JsmithDS</res-ref-name>
        <res-type>javax.sql.DataSource</res-type>
        <res-auth>Container</res-auth>
    </resource-ref>

</web-app>
```

Comment: Did you check a deployment descriptor?

Comment: i updated this question to show my web xml file... is it right

Comment: There should be more specific error messages in the log file somewhere. If you find those and update your question it might be easier to help. Generally, there are multiple potential reasons why a war file that works in tomcat does not in JBoss. Popular among those are: Tomcat allows you to define datasources in the war file, JBoss does not; and You can encounter Classpath problems if you include jar files in your war that are also included in JBoss, e.g. logging libraries etc....

Answer (score 0):

Please delete following wars from your war

web-inf/lib

```
 xercesImpl.jar and xml-apis.jar
```

It will deploy on jboss